# What is a trait in Azure ML matchbox recommender?

Tags: azure, recommendation-engine, azure-machine-learning-service

Azure Machine Learning has an item called `Train Matchbox Recommender`. It can be configured with a `Number of traits`. Unfortunately, the documentation does not describe what such a trait is.

What are traits? Is this related to [latent variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_variable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://apprize.info/microsoft/azure_1/9.html) page may have better descriptions on it.

Basically, traits are the features the algorithm will learn about each user related to each item. For example, in the [restaurant ratings recommender](https://gallery.azure.ai/Experiment/Recommender-Restaurant-ratings-2) traits could include a user's birth year, if they're a student or working professional, martial status, etc.

Hope that helps!

Comment: In the restaurant rating example you are linking, would you agree that the number of traits is 4 for latitude, longitude, interest, personality?

Comment: Yeah, I would agree with that :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion yes, this is related to latent variables and defines the dimensions of the compressed trait matrix. The columns of this matrix - the latent trait vectors - can be interpreted as stereotypes of users. Hence, the `number of traits` corresponds with the number of stereotype users in the recommendation model.

You can find more explanation in the corresponding research paper ["Matchbox: Large Scale Bayesian Recommendations"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/matchbox-large-scale-bayesian-recommendations/):

> Users and items are represented by feature vectors which are mapped into a low-dimensional 'trait-space' in which similarity is measured in terms of inner products ([source](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/matchbox-large-scale-bayesian-recommendations/)).

In classical Collaborative Filtering this latent representation is often computed using Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) through least-squares method and selecting only the first/largest k dimensions of this matrix. This reduces the dimensionality of the user-item-rating matrix. In this [Hacker Noon article by Steeve Huang](https://hackernoon.com/introduction-to-recommender-system-part-1-collaborative-filtering-singular-value-decomposition-44c9659c5e75) you can find a more detailed explanation.

Update 1: added interpretation of latent vectors